# Fourier Transform of ECG signal in Python

Tags: fourier-transform, python, ecg

I have an ECG signal which I am analyzing using Python, as opposed to the mainstream MATLAB. So, I have digital form ECG in .dat file with .hea (header file). Below is the Fourier transform 
[image: Fourier transform of ECG signal]

The problem, as you can see, that it is not the correct Fourier transform. Below is my code.

```
import wfdb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from scipy import fftpack

cutoff = float(input("Cutoff: "))
cutoff = cutoff/(360.)
noiseAmp = float(input("Noise Amplitude: "))
programed_to = 5000

# load the aami3a ECG signal using special package wfdb for python.
record = wfdb.rdrecord('aami3a', sampto=programed_to, physical=False) # digital data, hence physical=False

# 2D numpy array storing the actual signal data. record is an object of wfdb which has many attributes.
# one of those attributes fs (sampling frequency) and d_signal which stores the amplitude at various times.
original = record.d_signal
# define time of 5000 length
t = np.arange(0, (1/record.fs)*programed_to, 1/record.fs)
# define a sinusoidal noise.
noise = noiseAmp*np.cos(2*np.pi*50*t)

# add noise to the ecg signal
record.d_signal = record.d_signal.flatten() + noise
# make the signal again a 2D array.
record.d_signal = np.reshape(record.d_signal, (-1, 1))

# define a fifth order butterworth lowpass filter with cutoff/fs/2 = 0.11 (tunable).
b, a = signal.butter(5, cutoff, 'lowpass', False)
# apply this low pass filter on the noisy ecg.
output_signal = signal.filtfilt(b, a, record.d_signal.flatten())


# plotting the FFT of the signal
# fft of the original signal.
org_fft = np.fft.fft(original)
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(original.size, 1/720.)
f1 = plt.figure()
A1 = f1.add_subplot(211)
A1.plot(freq, np.abs(org_fft))
plt.show()
```

I think I have taken Fourier transform correctly. Please help.

Comment: **Why** is that not the "right Fourier transform"? Can you elaborate on what the problem with that plot is?

Comment: Because, there would be a single peak at 0 frequency.

Comment: Absolutely not, unless you're only observing noise and the patient has been dead for quite a while.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so a little trick and the transform would be correct. The problem is on last 6th line. Instead of `np.fft.fft(original)`, it should be `np.fft.fft(np.array(origitnal).flatten())`. I think that the wrong results were because `original` was a 2D numpy array.